# How to automate the task of copying files from one directory to another using Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am new to Camel. I tried a simple example of creating a route to copy files from one directory to another. I am using simple from and .to methods to do the same.

```
           from("file:input?noop=true")
               .to("file:output");
```

But for copying any new file that has been added to the input directory I need to run the code again. I know that this task can be automated but I am confused with so many options. Can anyone suggest different ways to automate this task?
Thanks

Comment: This route will continue picking up files from the input folder until the Camel application is stopped. You should not have to restart that application.

Comment: Hi @SneharghyaPathak , I want to add a timer like after every 5 minutes it should check for any new files in the directory and if there are any then copy it to the output directory. Can you guide me how to do it ?

Comment: Akash, Camel polls the files automatically every 0.5 seconds. If you want to poll every 5 minutes, you can add a delay option. Something like this `file:input?noop=true&delay=30000"`

Comment: Okay. I'll post this as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camel polls the files automatically every 0.5 seconds. If you want to poll every 5 minutes, you can add a delay option. Something like this `file:input?noop=true&delay=30000"`